# I am making a qt Browser and converting it in .exe and its showing this error

Tags: pyinstaller

```
[18276:11728:0812/095953.281:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(262)] Network service crashed, restarting service.
```

while I am opening my browser

This is made on python and is a pyqt5 application.

Please help and tell me the solution for this.

This is an example of my code

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
import os
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Can you provide us a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code?

Comment: Ok I have done you can see.

Comment: I don't have knowledge about this, but emm, maybe its [fixed](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-91715)?